What are the rules for editting a question
I editted a question (I changed the question to a tangential issue I asked what I should have done in that scenario that I thought I should ask a new question) after it was closed as a duplicate but it didn't have any answers yet.
The question is
What are the rules on editting questions (especially if they are closed as duplicates but don't have answers yet); especially what is the spirit of the rule?
I was told I am a rules lawyer. I don't know much about slang. I read that the term denotes someone with an overly-literal interpretation that is contrary to the rules' intent, who attempts to use the letter of the law without reference to the spirit.
I appreciate that it is offensive and insulting to change the question after it has been answered.
It implies disrespect for the person who spent time answering the question.
It can cause confusion in the community because of the lack of cohesion in Question and Answer.
But I don't see any harm (to the community, to the participants etc) when changing a question that hasn't been answered yet.
The question is closed (it will most probably be hidden and deleted) suggesting to just ask a new question if they have one is little more than pedantry.

Please refer to the tour.
Among other things, edits are encouraged "to clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)". The most egregious misuse of an edit is to change the meaning of the post in any way. To change the question changes the meaning. It is irrelevant if anyone has answered.
If no one has seen it, I think it would be fine to change the nature of the question, but if anyone other than yourself has seen it, then just chalk it up fate, and if you have a different question, just post a new question. The person who saw it might be in the middle of writing an answer you can't yet see! (This has happened to me.)
The intent is many fold: to avoid vandalism, to avoid rudeness by wasting people's time, etc. If people have invested time in/with the question - even just to read and think of an answer, or have made comments asking for details, etc. - then let it be. It's based on kindness and consideration for the people in the community.

@GeorgeNtoulos - please read everything on https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites - there are loads more, but these are more than sufficient for the vast majority of folks
